# Number of graphs with $n$ edges

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I have been trying to count the number of graphs up to isomorphism which are:

1. Simple
2. Connected
3. Have $n$ edges.

I apologize in advance if there is ample documentation on this question; however, I have found none.
Thus far, my best overestimate is:
$$g(n) = \sum_{i=x}^y t(i) \cdot  \binom{a(i)} { n - i - 1}$$

where:

$g(n) := $ the number of such graphs with $n$ edges,

$t(i) :=$ the number of trees up to isomorphism on $i$ vertices,

$a(i) :=$ the number of non-adjacent vertices in a tree on $i$ vertices.

I have conjectured that:
$$a(i) = \sum_{k-1}^i (i - k),
\qquad y = n+1,\quad\text{and}$$
$x \geq $
the number of vertices in the complete graph with the closest number of edges to $n$, rounded down.

I have also read that
the number of trees including isomorphism with $i$ vertices is $i^{i-2}$,
and have placed that as the upper bound for $t(i)$.

And that [according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Unlabeled_trees)] there is an estimate for the number of such trees up to isomorphism:
$t(i)\sim C  \alpha^i  i^{-5/2}$
with $C=0.534949606...$ and $\alpha=2.99557658565...$.

What I would like to know is:

> A.  Is there an answer already found for this question?
>
> B.  Is there any information off the top of your head which might assist me?
>
> C.  Is this problem incredibly hard?

Again, I apologize if this is not appropriate for this site.
I am a sophomore undergraduate student, and I have been trying to answer or estimate this question for use as an upper bound for another larger question that I am working on.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Get the first few values, then look 'em up at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. 

Comment: A. I doubt an exact number is known but I am pretty sure the question has been asked before and there is a lot of literature; B the rough order is $e^{n\log n}$ (give or take a constant factor in the exponent). C. That depends on the precision you want. The crude estimate I quoted is trivial but the more accurate bounds you want, the harder it gets.

Comment: It is certainly not the state of the art but a quick literature search yields the asymptotics $\left[\frac 2e\frac n{\log^2 n}\gamma(n)\right]^n$ with $\gamma(n)=1+c(n)\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}$ and $c(n)$ eventually between $2$ and $4$. Is it good enough for your purposes?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This will be enough to place an upper bound on what I was looking for, though I'm afraid I vastly underestimated the order of magnitude.  Because of this, I doubt I'll be able to use this to produce a close estimate.  

For anyone interested in further pursuing this problem on it's own.  If there is an estimate available for the average number of spanning trees in an n-vertex simple graph, I believe dividing the sum that I proposed:
g(n) = The sum (t(i) * (a(i) choose (n - i - 1))) from i=x to y
by a manipulation of this number may provide an estimate.    

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68017/counting-non-isomorphic-graphs-with-prescribed-number-of-edges-and-vertices/68024#68024

Answer (score 4):

Start here and you might find more.

http://oeis.org/A002905