# Counting non-isomorphic graphs with prescribed number of edges and vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics

I'd love your help with this question.

Let $n\geq3$ be a fixed integer. How many non-isomorphic graphs with $p$ vertices and $q$ edges are there where $p+q=n$?

Thank you very much.

Crossposted at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45815/counting-graphs-with-fixed-ve).

Comment: I changed the tags. On a different note, this question could do with some attention from the points at http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask - for example, what is your motivation? How did this question come up?

Comment: This duplicates a question at math.stackexchange. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45815/counting-graphs

Comment: Blaise - the usual practice is to not ask in both MO and math.SE at the same time. Usually (as in, almost always) a question will only be suitable for one of them, it may be that the asker misjudges the 'audience', and so needs to swap to the other.

Answer (score 23):

Using the Combinatorica package in  Mathematica, the command NumberOfGraphs$[p,q]$ returns the number of non-isomorphic graphs with $p$ vertices and $q$ edges.  If you want to implement this yourself, you may want to proceed [here](http://www.roard.com/docs/cookbook/cbsu5.html) first.

There is an explicit (but rather complicated) formula which you can find [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html).  The formula is obtained via [Pólya's Enumeration Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem).

Edit: Indeed it is a standard application of Pólya theory to obtain formulas for the number of nonisomorphic graphs with $p$ vertices and $q$ edges. (Counting the number where the total number of vertices and edges is $n$ can be obtained from this.) The standard book on graph enumeration is "Graphical enumeration" by Harary and Palmer. There is a [web site](http://oeis.org/HPGE.html) with many sequences arising from results discussed in the book.

Comment: Wow! Never in a million years would I have guessed there was an explicit formula, and what a formula it is!